# How to control the serialization of types in RouteValueDictionary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, model-binding

I have code that builds Urls in ASP.NET MVC3 using a RouteValueDictionary and UrlHelper. The problem that I am running into is that MVC calls ToString() on the types in the dictionary. For a particular type I am using, this is not the value that I want to be in the Uri. I cannot change the ToString implementation.

I understand how to create a ModelBinder to handle the deserialization from the Uri, but not the serialization part. How and what do I register in order to control how a type is converted to the Uri parameter?

Thanks,
Erick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a particular type I am using, this is not the value that I want to be in the Uri

Then don't use this type. Pass the value that you want directly as string in the dictionary:

```
rvd["key"] = "the value you want";
```

instead of:

```
rvd["key"] = new SomeType { Foo = "foo", Bar = "bar" };
```

The conversion between your type and its string representation should be handled elsewhere.

Comment: Is that the only way to do it? It seems like there should some sort of serialization service you could plug into.

Comment: No there isn't any serialization service you can *plugin in*.